# current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated in mongoDB, Node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, windows

I am learning NodeJS in w3schools.com at this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb_create_db.asp), in MongoDB section i get error and i can't solve it.

```
Create a database called "mydb":
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb";

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log("Database created!");
  db.close();
});
```

Save the code above in a file called "demo_create_mongo_db.js" and run the file
`C:\Users\myName>node demo_create_mongo_db.js` 
then i get this error

```
(node:6104) DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to the MongoClient constructor.
C:\Users\Milad\node_modules\mongodb\lib\utils.js:725
          throw error;
          ^

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1137:16) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Milad\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\topologies\server.js:438:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at C:\Users\Milad\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:561:14
    at C:\Users\Milad\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\pool.js:994:11
    at C:\Users\Milad\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:31:7
    at callback (C:\Users\Milad\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:264:5)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Milad\node_modules\mongodb\lib\core\connection\connect.js:294:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:418:26)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:92:8) {
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {}
}
```

I tried the next chapter lesson but get the same error.
I am using windows10x64

Answer (score 0):

First install [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center)!
I thought Node.js had installed MongoDB on my machine.

Answer (score -1):

before running node app you should first install mango on your machine
check on the below link how to download and install it:
https://www.mongodb.com/try/download/community